# Sourcetree cloning a repository, authentication issue

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to clone a git repository on both 2 PCs.
I have 1 account and 1 version of Sourcetree.

***The first PC***
can clone the repo without issues.

***The second PC***
lets me log in and browse all my repos, but there is an issue while cloning.

```
Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks ls-remote https://HugoVrana@bitbucket.org/HugoVrana/musicshop_aspnet.git
Output: 
Error: remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/HugoVrana/musicshop_aspnet.git/'
```

Git version 2.29.2.2

Sourcetree version 3.3.9

Why can I log in to my account, browse my repos, but when I want to clone a repo, there is an authentication issue?

Comment: What is “checkout a repo”? Do you mean clone?

Comment: The credentials are wrong. Did you double checked them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have it working based off this article:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Cannot-clone-repo-from-bitbucket-get-invalid-username-error/qaq-p/1713184

While I did not need to reset my password, I removed all Sourcetree, Atlassian, and GitHub folders under my AppData folders.

I did not need to remove the Git folder under C:\Program Files\Git where I had git-bash.exe.